# Out of memory (allocated 363593728) (tried to allocate 40000 bytes)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get this error when users are uploading images on my site.

Error msg is:

> PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 80740352) (tried to allocate
>   12352 bytes) in /album.......

How can I fix this?

I am used this function for that `imagecreatefromjpeg($image);`
and on the start of the page I have set the limit `ini_set('memory_limit', '2024M');`

Below code I used to image make thumb.

```
$mime = $info['mime'];
        if ($mime == 'image/gif') {
            return imagecreatefromgif($image);
        } elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {
            return imagecreatefrompng($image);
        } elseif ($mime == 'image/jpeg') {
            //ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
            //ini_set("memory_limit","5000M");
            echo ini_get('memory_limit');

            //ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
            //ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
            $imageReturn = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
            imagedestroy($imageReturn);
            print_r($imageReturn);
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the memory limit gets raised to 2024M?

Comment: Yes, I check that using the "ini_get('memory_limit')"

Comment: Is the call to that piece of code within a loop at all?

Comment: I am get the solution using http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php functionality. Thanks Frnz

Answer (score 0):

Most probabile you have an infinite loop some where in your code.